# The network connection to ****** has been lost. Debugging will be aborted

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm getting this error message when I run my UWP (Windows 10) application with the target set to "Device" (using my Windows Phone).

It says "Deploying" and suddenly fails. Usually, VS crashes and restarts. I have just installed Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.

What can I do to fix it? I cannot run my app on my phone.

Comment: please reset your phone, test it again. Like this link here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 •To test apps on a Windows Phone 8 device:

(1)The Windows Phone IP over USB Transport service must be running. This service is installed and started when you install the Windows Phone SDK 8.0.


(2)The computer must recognize the connected device. A Windows Phone 8 phone is listed as a drive in File Explorer.

Comment: It's a Windows 10 device. The service is running and I restarted everything. No luck :(

Comment: @ SuperJMN， can you share the detailed output information in the output window? I just met this kind of error before which was related to the USB ports or the VM Workstation and VM Player like this case: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6c915530-8137-4ddc-b286-b693c9f05527/the-network-connection-to-1270018116-has-been-lost-debugging-will-be-aborted?forum=wpdevelop, but not very sure that whether you got the same issue in your side. I think we need to collect the detailed error message or debug output messages.

Comment: It's really confusing. Today I have managed to debug the application. I did nothing and changed nothing. The first time I ran it, it shown the same error the title says, but after some attempts, the application was deployed and debugging. I will keep on looking to this issue. BTW, I don't have VMware installed, but Hyper-V.

Comment: @ SuperJMN, "after some attempts" means that just debugging it for several times, am I right? Maybe it really met certain network connection issue during connecting the device or others for the first time. If this issue has been resolved, maybe you could just use your reply as the provisional answer. Of course, if it has this issue again, please free to share it here using the comment:)

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered what was wrong!

**It was due to a "bad" USB 3.0 connection.**

I was connecting using a **USB 3.0 hub**. It seems the connections using my hub are somewhat unstable. I solved my issue connecting my Lumia directly to one of the USB ports the come directly from the motherboard.

Now, it works flawlessly!